# Org Table from python array

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am having some issues with outputting my python array to an org table.

In short I have an array as such :
`[[headerA, headerB],[data,data],[data, data]]`
Anyway my code is setup as follows:

```
#+begin_src python :tangle yes :exports both :session 
def table():
       # Some code that fills data
       tableData = [[headerA, headerB],[data,data],[data, data]]
       return tableData

table()
#+end_src
```

Now this gives me no results. But if I add `:results output`, and then copy the output. AKA my ready to go table. Then:

```
#+begin_src python :tangle yes :exports both :session 
def table():
       return [[headerA, headerB],[data,data],[data, data]]

table()
#+end_src
```

It produces my table with no issues. If anyone knows why this is happening, or if it is a bug.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to clarify this a bit. I have no idea what you mean when you talk about `:results outputs`. It certainly doesn't correspond to anything in the code. Both examples you give should do the same thing, provided you populate the header and data fields in the `table()` function.

Comment: Hi, do you have experience with org-babel? Don't mean to be rude, but If not, I don't know if the clarification would help as it seems to be a pretty particular case. But if you do, it should be `:results output' (Type). It is a org-babel function which basically tells org mode how to display the output of the code. By default it will provide a `#+RESULTS: ` filled with any returns, however in `:session` it will only provide returns from a ran function. To output a table it is left out but i used it to get the return from the function, which i then reused hence my strange case. Hope this helps

Comment: Nope, I hit this from the python tag. People tag things with all sorts, and it wasn't even clear to me that your question wasn't something I should bother looking at. But I'm out then.

Comment: If I fix the definition of tableData to make it legal python (I just made everything a string:  `tableData = [["headerA", "headerB"],["data","data"],["data", "data"]]`) I get a nice table with no problems. You don't show *where* you add the `:results output` above, but AFAICT it is not needed: both of the code blocks above without *ANY* changes except making everything a string, produce the same table.

Comment: Sorry, they are just placeholders, the actual data are floats. If i try `data = [[2,3],[4,4]]`, it does not create a table

Comment: Sure it does: `#+begin_src python :tangle yes :exports both :session 
def table():
       # Some code that fills data
       tableData = [[2, 3],[4, 5],[6,7]]
       return tableData

table()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 |` You will have to insert newlines to reconstitute it, but it works fine, assuming that you write legal python (e.g. `tableData`, *not* `data`).

Comment: BTW, what does `M-x org-version RET` say?

Comment: Thanks, it appears to work now. Org version is 9.3 :)